# Python csv import fails

Tags: python, csv, import

So I'm trying to use the csv module in python 3.3.2 but I am getting this error.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:\Users\massi_000\Desktop\csv.py", line 1, in <module>
         import csv
      File "C:\Users\massi_000\Desktop\csv.py", line 4, in <module>
        csv.reader(f)
    AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'reader'
```

Obviously I'm going something stupendously wrong but all the code I am using is below and it looks fine. Has something changed in this version that has rendered this code unusable or..?

```
import csv
f = open("test.csv")
csv.reader(f)
for row in csv_fi:
    print(row)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have named your file `csv.py` and this clashes with the `csv` module from the Python standard library.

You should rename your own file to something else so that `import csv` will import the standard library module and not your own. This can be confusing but this is a good rule-of-thumb going forward: avoid giving your own Python files names that are the same as modules in the standard library.

Answer (score 0):

As @Simeon Visser said, you have to rename your file but you have some other issues with your code as well. Try this:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', newline='') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=' ')
    for row in reader:
        print (', '.join(row))
```